# Regular expression to replace middle chars of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace middle 4 characters of a string with ****

For example: ABCDEFG should become AB****G

Please suggest a Regex to achieve this.

**Note:** The length of the string is always same.

Comment: If you replace the characters by index regex is not the solution here, regex can help you find patterns in a string why do you want to use regex ?

Comment: If your string is `s` you can do this: `s[:2] + "****" + s[6:]` no need for regex

Comment: @rkechols I'm especially looking for a regex.  Like the one that I've posted in the answers section

Comment: The question is **why** you're looking for regex. Not that what kind of regex you're looking for.

Comment: @JamesZ I was looking for a js one liner which can be incorporated in a html tag (update the value as and when the values are retrieved and view it in a table).   Now I've achieved it like:
`<td>tab.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML.replace(/\b(\w{2})\w+(\w)\b/g, '$1**$2')</td>` 
Also, there is nothing wrong in knowing how to do this in regex (even though there are alternate ways to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution that I was looking for:

var s="ABCDEFG"
var reg=/\b(\w{2})\w+(\w)\b/g

s.replace(reg, '$1**$2');

output:  AB****G

This will replace all the middle chars except first 2 and last 1 char in a string.